# How to install an older version of rabbitmq on 11.04?

Tags: 11.04, server

I can install the latest version of rabbitmq-server just fine using

```
sudo apt-get install rabbitmq-server
```

It installs version 2.3.1-1

I tried to install older versions by downloading the .deb file then installing the package

```
sudo dpkg -i rabbitmq-server_olderversion-1_all.deb
```

But I always get this error:

```
Not creating home directory `/var/lib/rabbitmq'.
Starting rabbitmq-server: TIMEOUT - check /var/log/rabbitmq/startup_{log,err}
rabbitmq-server.
invoke-rc.d: initscript rabbitmq-server, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing rabbitmq-server (--install):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
```

How can I install an older version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have some data from the newer version which may conflict with what the older version expects. It is unlikely that the older version knows how to downgrade the data fromats/configs etc from the new layout.

I had a similar problem when *upgrading* from some older version to 2.4.0 - on startup rabbitmq tried to upgrade its database but failed. Try uninstalling your current rabbitmq version, manually removing/renaming /var/lib/rabbitmq and then installing it again.